# URL Rewrite Redirect

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, query-string, iis-8

I dont understand writing URL Rewrite aspects yet.  But need assistance as I dont know what I am doing incorrectly.

My goal is when a USER clicks on a link

**www.example.com/NM/Registration?ctl=PasswordReset&resetToken=db08aa18-0810-417d-a633-131635bf9e8e**

I would like the user to be redirected to

**www.example.com/Registration?ctl=PasswordReset&resetToken=db08aa18-0810-417d-a633-131635bf9e8e**

As you can see I would like to redirect without the **NM** in the URL path to the root domain.

I have this in my web.config file but it seems that it wont redirect properly:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>

      <rule name="Query String Rewrite">
          <match url="/NM/Registration" />
          <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ctl=([a-z]+)" />
                    <add input="##{C:1}##_{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="##([^#]+)##_.*resetToken=([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/Registration?ctl={C:1}&amp;resetToken={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my answer.  I ended up rewriting the rule so hopefully this will help out anyone in the future.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>  

      <rule name="Query String For Redirect">
          <match url="NM/Registration" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="ctl=([a-z]+)&amp;resetToken=([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="Registration?ctl={C:1}&amp;resetToken={C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>                    

</rules>
</rewrite>
```